# How to install kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How to **install** `Kubernetes` and How to add `worker-nodes` to `Kubernetes-Master`

Comment: Consider to ask questions related to kubernetes installation on https://serverfault.com instead. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider **1** Kubernetes-Cluster and **2** Worker-Nodes

1. While launching AWS ec2 instances, make sure that you **open all the
   ports** in the related *security groups*.
2. All EC2 instances need to be on the *same VPC* and in the *same
   availability zone*.
3. For K8-Cluster minimum requirement is `t2.large`
4. For Worker-Nodes minimum requirement is `t2.micro`
5. Login to putty/terminal to connect to your EC2 instances.

### Run the following Commands on both K8-Cluster and Worker-nodes

- Be a root user. Install Docker and start Docker service. Also, enable
  the docker service so that the docker service starts on the system
  restarts.

```html
sudo su
yum install docker -y 
systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
```

- Create proper yum repo files so that we can use yum commands to install the components of Kubernetes.

```html
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]

name=Kubernetes

baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64

enabled=1

gpgcheck=1

repo_gpgcheck=0

gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg

exclude=kube*

EOF
```

- sysctl command is used to modify kernel parameters at runtime. Kubernetes needs to have access to the kernel’s IP6 table and so we need to do some more modifications. This includes disabling secure Linux.

```html
cat <<EOF >  /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF

sysctl --system
setenforce 0
```

- Install kubelet, kubeadm and kubectl; start kubelet daemon

```html
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
```

```html
vi /etc/docker/daemon.json

{
    "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
```

- restart docker and kubelet; reload daemon

```html
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl restart docker
 sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

---

**Only on the Master Node:**

- On the master node initialize the cluster.

```html
kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors all
```

- To make kubeconfig file permanent , paste the `export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` after `export PATH` in `.bash_profile`

```html
ls -al
vi .bash_profile
```

```html
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

---

**On All Worker nodes :**

- Copy kubeadm join command from the output of kubeadm init on the master node.

```html
<kubeadm join command copied from master node>

# kubeadm join 172.31.37.128:6443 --token sttk5b.vco0jw5bkkf1toa4 \
                 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:d77b5f865c1e30b73ea4dd7ea458f79f56da94f9de9c8d7a26b226d94fd0c49e
```

---

**On the Master Node :**

- Create weave-net.

```html
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

```html
kubectl get nodes
```

**That's it :)**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start Kubernetes on Amazon Linux AMI (or any other Linux AMI) is to use [Microk8s](https://microk8s.io) (a lightweight distribution of Kubernetes).

The following steps will help you get started with Kubernetes  on EC2 instance:

1. **Install Microk8s on EC2 instance**

   `sudo snap install microk8s --classic`
2. **Check the status while Kubernetes starts**

   `microk8s status --wait-ready`
3. **Turn on the services you want**

   `microk8s enable dashboard dns registry istio`
4. **Start using Kubernetes**

   `microk8s kubectl get all --all-namespaces`
5. **Access the Kubernetes dashboard**

   `microk8s dashboard-proxy`
6. **Start and stop Kubernetes to save battery**
   `microk8s start` and `microk8s stop`

This way you can install a local version of Kubernetes with Microk8s. You can also follow this [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s) for detailed instructions on the above steps.